# Issues with searches in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, bug, documentation, search

In any documentation topic, you can search through it (for topics and examples, it looks like).

I'll use the Java documentation search as an example:
[image]

We'll use Arrays as an example search term:
[image]

## Inconsistent Search Results

I type Arrays, and I get a list of related topics. When I hit enter, I expect it to take me to the most relevant topic (Arrays, in this case). However, I get seemingly unrelated results:
[image]

So, I get results that don't seem to match. In addition, Arrays is nowhere to be found. On top of that, it says there are 85 results, but I can only see 15 in total, and there doesn't appear to be pagination to the search results:

[image]

As you can see, there doesn't appear to be a next button (or any pagination buttons I have come to expect on SO pages, so I can't get to the additional results.

## Inability to Select search topic (with keyboard)

Searching for Arrays again, I see that "Arrays" is the top result, but I can't arrow down to it with my keyboard. This is a very common aspect of searches, and I keep searching for something, only to hit enter, not having selected a search result.

Of course, I can select it with my mouse, but that's an extra (and unnecessary) step.

Comment: Also, it perhaps should try to put a topic first, over the examples, even if it has a slightly lower relevancy score.

Comment: The current state of search in Docs is "We have it. It's not good, but we have it." Thanks for bringing this up. We'll definitely be looking into injecting some awesome into how search works both straight up within tags and in other areas like "most popular" searches or link insertion.

Comment: @AdamLear, while you're at it: Can you inject some awesomeness into the regular SO search too?

Comment: The fact that you even noticed that there are no links to other pages tells a lot about the (lack of) quality of results.

Comment: BTW the fact that there is no second page is also mentioned here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331682/5420829

Comment: I noticed a similar but a more bizarre issue: searching "[with](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=sql&query=with)" in the sql tag yields [a bunch of unrelated pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkWpa.png), however searching "[sql with](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=sql&query=sql+with)" yields [the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1eyS.png). This might have something to do with [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/topic-requests/23161), before that both searches were unhelpful.

Comment: @AdamLear - Is there an update on this? I tried [searching for `var`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=c%23&q=var) and just found most C# questions in no particular order...