# Documentation search is not displaying some results

Tags: bug, documentation, search

I searched for "reflection" in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) Documentation and received the results in the screenshot below.  The search claims there are 20 results, but only 15 are displayed, and there's no "next page" link.  I'm using 64-bit Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 7, with uBlock Origin disabled (and the block log confirms nothing was blocked or hidden).

[image: 20 results claimed, only 15 displayed]

Comment: Documentation is not easy to use if you actually want to find some information on a particular topic. All of the improvements seem to be aimed towards those creating and editing content. I expect it will get better once google is indexing stuff but right now not very good for people who might actually want to consume the documentation.

Comment: This issue was also mentioned here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329828/5420829