# Documentation search tooltip gives better results than the results listing itself

Tags: discussion, documentation, search

I'll start by saying I'm not sure if this is an issue, so I've tagged this as *discussion* for now.

Today I tried to look for [Using console.log()](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log#t=201704111207119077462) to include in an answer. In my haste, I entered "console" into the search field and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but to my dismay this topic was nowhere to be found:

> [image]

After submitting my answer I went back and found that if I'd waited a couple of seconds the article I was looking for would have been right there near the top of the prediction drop-down on the search box itself:

> [image]

---

A worse example of this in action is if I were to search for a symbol like `+`. The prediction drop-down gives me exactly what I want:

> [image]

Yet none of those entries are pulled through onto the results list when hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

> [image]

---

The search prediction drop-down appears to give a better set of results than the actual results list. This appears to happen because the prediction looks at titles whereas the results list looks at content (and appears to ignore titles(?)). Is this intentional?

Comment: Is this the same complaint as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329828/issues-with-searches-in-documentation ?

Comment: Seems like a classic case of "the formal search tool provides worse results than every other method of finding stuff" on Stack Overflow...